# What is the difference between Toggle and slideToggle in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("document").ready(function() {
 $("button").click(function() {
 $("[src$='.jpg']").slideToggle(1000);
  })
  }
)
</script>
<img src="http://images2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20101129232634/callofduty/images/2/2e/Pripyat.jpg">
<button>Click me</button>
```

is same like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("document").ready(function() {
 $("button").click(function() {
 $("img [src$='.jpg']").toggle(1000);
  })
  }
)
</script>
<img src="http://images2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20101129232634/callofduty/images/2/2e/Pripyat.jpg">
<button>Click me</button>
```

So is there really any difference?

Answer (score 7):

It should be pointed out however that there *is* a difference in the animation, albeit a small one: `.toggle()` will slide the element from the top left corner, whereas `.slideToggle` will slide it from top to bottom.

You can see an example for both effects on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eUY6F/6/).

Answer (score 3):

[.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/):

> Display or hide the matched elements.

[.slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/):

> Display or hide the matched elements with a sliding motion.

---

With *your* usage, you will not see a difference.

The jQuery [documentation site](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) is very good and should be the first place to look for this kind of question.

Comment: Can you expand on why in his particular usage he'll see no difference? I'm looking for this answer too. Thanks

Comment: @i-CONICA - Nothing different is done when either of these is called. The only parameter passed is the duration without anything else, the default behaviour will be identical.