# Animation triggering for the .hide() part of slideToggle, but not the .show() part

Tags: jquery

> When I use .slideToggle on an element, it doesn't display an animation
>   for the "show" event, but it does do an animation for the "hide" part of
>   the toggle.

I hope this is not an idiotic question, but i've been searching around and I cannot find an answer. I am just learning Jquery, so forgive me if i've made a simple mistake.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359320/what-is-the-difference-between-toggle-and-slidetoggle-in-jquery) other post asks a similar question, but the definitions (slide toggle: animation toggle: no animation) don't seem to work.

Here's the J fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/9jUNS/

Thanks for taking a look! 
-Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is arising because the way in which jQuery animates the span element causes the layout to take the default inline rendering of a span and display it with absolute positioning and block layout.

Update your CSS to the following:

```
.demo span {
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

This should correct the positioning and layout and let jQuery animate the elements correctly.

Comment: Whoops, looks like this solves it too. Both answers were really helpful, but I feel that Phil's solves the problem from a more holistic perspective and, as such, serves as a better overall answer for future noobies like myself.

Answer (score 0):

This worked upon editing your JSFiddle

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('div.demo').children('span').hide(700);  
                              $('div.demo h3').click(function() {
                                $(this).next().slideToggle(700);
                              });

    });
```

Looks like your ".hide()" was overriding the behavior provided by the slideToggle.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! So, in the future I should just declare a value for the .hide() function?