# responsive jquery nav interaction - issue on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

Requirement:
Horizontal nav in 900px or above and vertical in 900 below. but in 900 or below, the nav should hide by default and appear only when clicked on the "header"

What I have so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/0rmgpjtr/3/

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

$('.dropdown ul:first').show();
    $('.dropdown ul:first').css("display:table");
    $('.dropdown li').click(function (e) {
                $(this).addClass('active').siblings('li').removeClass('active');
                $(this).children('ul').slideToggle('fast');
                $(this).siblings('li').find('ul').slideUp('fast');
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();

          });
              $(document).on('click', function (event) {
                $('.dropdown li').children('ul').slideUp('fast');
              });

});
$(window).on("resize", function () {

     if($(window).width()<=900){
         console.log("800");
        $('.ch-logo').bind('click',function(){
            $('.dropdown').slideToggle('fast');
        })
    }else{
                 console.log("900+");
        $('.ch-logo').unbind()
    }

}).resize();
```

Issue:
1. binding and unbinding the header click event is not working
2. when i click on parent link to open subnav, it is flickering after i resize the browser - actually any interaction, starts flickering the menu, may be because its tied to resize function.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/extca38f/

```
$(window).on("resize", function () {

     if($(window).width()<=900){
         console.log("800");
         $('.dropdown').hide();
        $('.ch-logo').bind('click',function(){
            $('.dropdown').toggle();
        });
     }else{
         $('.dropdown').show();
     }
}).resize();
```

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work. Please check. When I resize from less than 900 to more , the menu disappears and never comes back and header link is not clickable

Answer (score 0):

Use `toggle` instead of `slidetoggle` [**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/extca38f/1/)

```
$(window).on("resize", function () {

     if($(window).width()<=900){
         console.log("800");
         $('.dropdown').hide();
        $('.ch-logo').bind('click',function(){
            $('.dropdown').toggle('slow');
        });
     }else{
         $('.dropdown').show();
     }
}).resize();
```

[**Check the differnce between toggle and slidetoggle**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359320/what-is-the-difference-between-toggle-and-slidetoggle-in-jquery)

Comment: same issue. works good on load, but after resize, click on header, it starts flicker.