# When would toggle be better than slideToggle in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-effects

I've been racking my mind and searching the internet furiously on this simple question: When would I ever want to use toggle instead of slideToggle? For everything I've done with jQuery effects (mostly toggling tables and table rows), slideToggle provides the superior visual effect IMO. So I am interested in finding a use case when toggle might be superior.

Anybody have any experience in preferring toggle over slideToggle for better visual effect?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359320/what-is-the-difference-between-toggle-and-slidetoggle-in-jquery

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a subtle difference between `.toggle` and `.slideToggle`

[.toggle()](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

> Display or hide the matched elements.

[.slideToggle()](https://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)

> Display or hide the matched elements with a sliding motion.

In the following example, there is no parameter provided, so `.toggle` instantly hides the element, whereas `.slideToggle` slides it up

```js
$("#toggle").toggle();
$("#slide").slideToggle();
```

```css
#toggle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

#slide {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="toggle">

</div>
<div id="slide">

</div>
```

Whereas in this example, I've specified the toggles to take 1000ms, and you can see the difference in their animations

```js
$("#toggle").toggle(1000);
$("#slide").slideToggle(1000);
```

```css
#toggle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

#slide {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="toggle">

</div>
<div id="slide">

</div>
```

As for which one you want to use, obviously, it's context dependent.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of this functionality. My question is: In what context would you / have you ever used toggle(1000) over slideToggle(1000)

Comment: I probably can't name a specific time when I've needed one or the other, but if you are developing for a very specific look or feel, I can see why you might choose one or the other